# Can any application create Connectors for itself in Groups?

Tags: office365connectors

We would like to use the connectors feature to give users access to information from our line of business system inside groups. This seems possible using the webhooks method mentioned, but how do we get our connector in the list of Connectors our users can access?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, Incoming WebHooks allow you to build your own connectors.
You would be able to submit custom built Connectors to the 'Connector Store' as soon as connectors are out of developer preview.

Until then, you can facilitate connections to Office365 directly from your LOB applications using the '[Connect to Office 365 button](https://dev.outlook.com/Connectors/ConnectButton)'. This way you can abstract out copy-pasting WebHook URLs from your end users.